Is there a way to make an updated list of all the required ingredients in google sheets?
I am trying to make a list of all of the recipes in Stardew Valley, what ingredients are required for each of them, how the recipe is unlocked, and what ingredients are needed for the recipes I haven't cooked yet.  For example, if I need 4 blueberries in total, It will say that I need 4 blueberries. If I update the spreadsheet and mark one of the recipes as completed, it will update the amount of blueberries I still need.



Cooked
Meal
Ingredients
Ingredients#
Recipe Source




Cooked
Fried Egg
Egg (Any)
1
Starter


Not Cooked
Omelet
Egg (Any)
1
Queen of Sauce 28 Spring, Year 1


Not Cooked
Omelet
Milk (Any)
1
Queen of Sauce 28 Spring, Year 1



This is a rough summary of what the table looks like (I've already completed it). The "Meal" cells are merged for each recipe. I could either download the table as a csv and put it into a program like R each time I update a column, but that would be a last resort. I have created a list of unique values using the functions =UNIQUE(C2:C203) and =SUMIF(C2:C203, G2:G, D2:D203) I created a list of every unique ingredient needed and how many I need. I have tried to use the SUMIFS function to check whether the mean is cooked or not using =SUMIFS(C2:C203, G2:G203, D2:D203, A2:A203, "Not Cooked") but it always returns a value of 0.

What is the input in your table and what part is the expected output?

What have you tried? A query will do the trick.

I was able to get it to work. I used the code =SUMIFS(D2:D203, A2:A203, "Not Cooked", C2:C203, G2:G203). I'm not sure why switching the order of the criteria changed the output to one that worked, perhaps by starting with the criterion which applies to every row it allows for the second criterion to be one which has less rows, since there are less unique ingredients then there are ingredient entries next to the meals.
